# How to change installation directory for new google drive for windows10 and sync offline files?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, google-drive

After Google forced the new Google Drive for Desktop to Backup and Sync users, it deleted over half my files. And I can not locate where are the offline files are saving either. Now I uninstall the app.

Does anyone have experience with how to install the new Google Drive and keep files offline while syncing enable?

Note: I do not want to save files on C: dive on windows 10. How can I change offline files to a different directory?

Answer (score 2):

Please follow the below steps to move offline file cache in Windows 10:

- Create a folder for your offline file cache. Something like D:\Offline.
- From an elevated command prompt type the following: Takeown /r /f C:\Windows\CSC.
- Open the Sync Center and go to Manage Offline Files.
- Click Disable Offline Files and restart the machine.
- From an elevated command prompt issue the following commands:

rd /s C:\Windows\CSC
mklink /J C:\Windows\CSC "D:\Offline"
(or whatever your folder name is, but be sure to use the quotes if you have space(s) in the name).

- Reopen the Manage Offline Files window and Enable Offline Files.
- Restart the machine.
  All files/folders that are made available offline should now be redirected to whichever folder you specified.

I hope this information is helpful. Please post in case you have any further issues, we will be glad to help you further.

Comment: Totally unix style.  Note the way she uses a junction to trick the program rather than messing with settings (which are probably not even an option).  I use this trick all the time with ANY APP that I don't like where it put stuff.  NICE JOB Amelia!

Comment: thx Señor CMasMas

Comment: @AmeliaSanderas Thank you very much for your kind reply. I have tried to follow your steps. However I get an error. I don't have programming skills unfortunately.                                                        C:\WINDOWS\system32>Takeown /r /f C:\Windows\CSC
ERROR: The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: I searched where is CSC. It's located at C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\csc.exe   So I tried  C:\WINDOWS\system32>Takeown /r /f C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\csc
ERROR: The system cannot find the file specified.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>Takeown /r /f C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\csc.exe
ERROR: The specified path is not a valid directory path.
. As said before I have no programming skill @AmeliaSanderas

Comment: Try (from an elevated command prompt) changing the command to `Takeown /r /f %windir%\CSC`  Your search for CSC found a program that is part of .net, not the folder miss Amelia was referring to.  Trust me, the folder is there.  Try again.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Thank you. Still I get the Error message C:\WINDOWS\system32>Takeown /r /f %windir%\CSC
ERROR: The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: There is something going on because those commands *should have* worked.  We *could* beat a dead horse figuring it out.. but instead, lets try using the explorer to [take ownership](https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/take-ownership-folder-windows-10-using-file-explorer) of stuff.  This might be easier for you if you are more of a graphical person.  Open the explorer.  Find your windows directory, then CSC.  Right click and follow the instructions provided in the link.